# Find sequences in time series data using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, time-series

I'm trying to find example Elasticsearch queries for returning sequences of events in a time series. My dataset is rainfall values at 10-minute intervals, and I want to find all storm events. A storm event would be considered continuous rainfall for more than 12 hours. This would equate to 72 consecutive records with a rainfall value greater than zero. I could do this in code, but to do so I'd have to page through thousands of records so I'm hoping for a query-based solution. A sample document is below.

I'm working in a University research group, so any solutions that involve premium tier licences are probably out due to budget.

Thanks!

```
{
  "_index": "rabt-rainfall-2021.03.11",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "fS0EIngBfhLe-LSTQn4-",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2021-03-11T16:00:07.637Z",
    "current-rain-total": 8.13,
    "rain-duration-in-mins": 10,
    "last-recorded-time": "2021-03-11 15:54:59",
    "rain-last-10-mins": 0,
    "type": "rainfall",
    "rain-rate-average": 0,
    "@version": "1"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-03-11T16:00:07.637Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1615478407637
  ]
}
```

**Update 1**

Thanks to @Val my current query is

```
GET /rabt-rainfall-*/_eql/search
{
  "timestamp_field": "@timestamp",
  "event_category_field": "type",
  "size": 100,
  "query": """
    sequence
      [ rainfall where "rain-last-10-mins" > 0 ]
      [ rainfall where "rain-last-10-mins" > 0 ]
    until [ rainfall where "rain-last-10-mins" == 0 ]
  """
}
```

Having a sequence query with only one rule causes a syntax error, hence the duplicate. The query as it is runs but doesn't return any documents.

**Update 2**

Results weren't being returned due to me not escaping the property names correctly. However, due to the two sequence rules I'm getting matches of length 2, not of arbitrary length until the stop clause is met.

```
GET /rabt-rainfall-*/_eql/search
{
  "timestamp_field": "@timestamp",
  "event_category_field": "type",
  "size": 100,
  "query": """
    sequence
      [ rainfall where `rain-last-10-mins` > 0 ]
      [ rainfall where `rain-last-10-mins` > 0 ]
    until [ rainfall where `rain-last-10-mins` == 0 ]
  """
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample document of your index just so we can see the kind of fields we can play with?

Comment: @Val I've updated the question with a sample document

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely be a job for [EQL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eql.html) which allows you to return sequences of related data (ordered in time and matching some constraints):

```
GET /rabt-rainfall-2021.03.11/_eql/search?filter_path=-hits.events
{
  "timestamp_field": "@timestamp",
  "event_category_field": "type",
  "size": 100,
  "query": """
    sequence with maxspan=12h
      [ rainfall where `rain-last-10-mins` > 0 ]
    until `rain-last-10-mins` == 0
  """
}
```

What the above query seeks to do is basically this:

- get me the sequence of events of type `rainfall`
- with `rain-last-10-mins > 0`
- happening within a 12h window
- up until `rain-last-10-mins` drops to 0

The `until` statement makes sure that the sequence "expires" as soon as an event has `rain-last-10-mins: 0` within the given time window.

In the response, you're going to get the number of matching events in `hits.total.value` and if that number is 72 (because the time window is limited to 12h), then you know you have a matching sequence.

So your "storm" signal here is to detect whether the above query returns `hits.total.value: 72` or lower.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, but in theory it should work the way I described.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added an update to see the current query more clearly

Comment: makes sense... what do you get if you run the query with only the following content `rainfall where "rain-last-10-mins" > 0` ?

Comment: I didn't get anything either, then I figured out I need to escape the property names with backticks rather than quotes. I'm now getting results for the sequences, but the need for at least two sequence rules is causing it only to return sequences of length == 2. I can prove this by adding a third rule, then it matches sequences of length == 3. I'll update the post with the latest query

Comment: Good call about back ticks. What do you get if you remove the sequence altogether and only query what I suggested above?

Comment: I get a single events array with all records that have a rainfall-last-10-mins over 0

Comment: Ok, makes sense, that's not going to cut it, though... let me think about it a little bit more

Comment: I thought about a hack to programmatically build up a CURL request with 72 sequence rules but then realised I want to catch storms longer than 12 hours. So in plain English, my search is "find all rainfall events that are at least 12 hours long"